# Getting current version of Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I'm having a problem with installscript, and I'm trying to get the OS Version and detect if it's windows 10.

The Key that I'm trying to get is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\[CurrentVersion]
```

Using regedit, Windows 10 has the value 6.3 there. The same has Windows 8.1 and Windows 2012.

But, if I use WINVER on commandline, I get 10.0. How can this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of reading the value `CurrentVersion`, read the new values `CurrentMajorVersionNumber` (which is 10) and `CurrentMinorVersionNumber` (which is currently 0) under Windows 10. Those [2 keys are new in Windows 10 to detect Windows Version from Registry](https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl/pull/18/files#diff-ea48926a7d3868ba7cb1597fc48cff54R3868).

Answer (score 1):

At runtime, you need to have your application manifested correctly in order to get the right value from the version checking APIs; see [this MSDN topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241(v=vs.85).aspx) on how to set it up, and then you can use the [Version Helper APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241(v=vs.85).aspx#base.version_helper_apis) to get the right value. I don't know how much of that you can do within your installer project though.